# Disable weird trackpad scrolling behavior w/ iTerm and Vim

Tags: vim

When I accidentally hit the track pad in Vim it scrolls up to a "new" vim pane.  I'm not actually sure what entity it's scrolling up into, but here's what it looks like:

https://i.imgur.com/RC1U6Kc.gif

Any thoughts on how to prevent this from happening

Here's my `.vimrc` file:

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" Add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle used Bundle instead of Plugin)
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'auto-pairs-gentle'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required


let g:AutoPairsUseInsertedCount = 1
set backspace=indent,eol,start " backspace over everything in insert mode

autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") | exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | ene | endif


let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['flake8']
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--ignore=D100,D101,D103,D104,D105,I002,E501'


autocmd vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif


if has('gui_running')
    set background=dark
    colorscheme solarized
else
    colorscheme zenburn
endif

set nu

let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$', '\~$'] "ignore files in NERDTree
let NERDTreeAutoDeleteBuffer = 1
let NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let NERDTreeDirArrows = 1
map <silent> <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

set splitbelow
set splitright

nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>

" Enable folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=120

" Enable folding with the spacebar
nnoremap <space> za

let g:SimpylFold_docstring_preview=1

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=120 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix


set encoding=utf-8

let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

fun! TrimWhitespace()
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    %s/\s\+$//e
    call winrestview(l:save)
endfun


noremap <ScrollWheelUp>      <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelUp>    <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelUp>    <nop>
noremap <ScrollWheelDown>    <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelDown>  <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelDown>  <nop>
noremap <ScrollWheelLeft>    <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelLeft>  <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelLeft>  <nop>
noremap <ScrollWheelRight>   <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
```

Comment: `set mouse=a` should help.

Comment: @romainl this worked! add as an answer and i will accept